# Compare two objects

Tags: vertices, geometry

Can one compare the geometry of two objects and show how/where they differ?  Thought this would be an existing built-in feature, but I've been unable to find anything on it.

Occasionally I have two objects, and one may have been tweaked a little bit, but I don't remember the details of what I had been doing, and maybe I've been poor in my object naming. I would like to pick one object and request "compare" or "diff" then chose a another object as comparator. Then I'd see if they're the same or different, and if different, maybe highlight the geometry where they differ.

Occasionally I might duplicate an object but not get around to altering it, so would like to just delete it on the next visit, but don't want to delete it if it turns out to be an incremental improvement.

Currently using Blender 2.90 on MacOS 11. Current use is for designing 3Dprintable objects.

Answer (score 4):

This geometry nodes setup (3.2 version) may help you find differences:

[image]

The Geometry Nodes:

[image]

Shader:

[image]

[image]

If you have added points, switch *Transfer Attribute* node mode from *Index* to *Nearest*

Comment: very nice!!!!!! Geometry nodes is jus amazing! +1

Comment: thats pretty awesome!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Blender does not have a built-in 3D models compare functionality. Autodesk has one though [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Document-Management/files/About-Comparing-2D-and-3D/GUID-1872D1A7-1973-4715-BD99-13D766C18DFB-html.html) but they only support their own proprietary file types RVT, DWG, DXF, IFC, NWD, F3D. There's also a [3D Files Diff](https://github.blog/2013-09-17-3d-file-diffs/) software that might be useful. There are numerous other CAD software that let you compare 3D models such as MagicCheck, KeyCreator Direct CAD, CompareVidia, Solidworks, EnSuite, CADIQ, AutoVue. Other than that, when worse comes to worst, you could manually export one .OBJ file for v1 and another for v2 of the 3D model and use the [diff command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diff-command-linux-examples/amp/) `diff v1.obj v2.obj` to see textual differences.